# Cant put Apps on iPhone any more

Tags: iphone, bootstrapping, hung

Couldn't register com.mycompany.clack with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Program received signal: “SIGABRT”.

This is the error I get, any ideas on that? Restarting and so on does not help, it doesn't seem to be a Caching problem, any advice - none of the other forums had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I reinstalled the current OS on the Phone, that helped. Thought I had done that before - I surely have, just maybe not at the appropriate time....

Hope this can help anyone.